# PySpark: splitting multiple columns dynamically using for loop using comma as separator

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe as follows:

```
Col_1    Col_2             Col_3           Col_4
st2      ,08/06/2022,15    Nick,Davos      st4
st_r5    ,08/12/2021,33    Daniel,Jonas    st88
```

As it can be seen that in `Col_2` and in `Col_3` we have values that are separated by comma.
I want to use `pyspark.sql.function.split()` to get the values in a new column.

So I am using the below piece of codes:

```
col_size = df.select(F.size(F.split(F.col('Col_2'),",")).alias('Col_2'))
col_max = col_size.agg(F.max('Col_2'))
col_nos = col_max.collect()[0][0]

##Finally the dataframe##
df = df.select(*[df['Col_2'][x] for x in range(col_nos)])

##Dropping the Null columns##
n_t_cols = df.select([F.count(F.when((F.col(c).isNull()),c)).alias(c) \
       for c in df_f.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
to_drop = [k for k,v in n_t_cols.items() if v=df_count()]
df_f = df.drop(*to_drop)
```

My question is how can I iterate the above code on multiple columns? In other words, would the below code work?

```
for c in df.columns:
  ##--above code pieces. only to replace 'Col_2' by c--##
```

My final outcome should be like below:

```
    Col_1      Col_2      Col_3       Col_4     Col_5      Col_6
    st2     08/06/2022      15        Nick      Davos      st4
   st_r5    08/12/2022      33        Daniel    Jonas      st88
```

The null columns would have to be dropped.